# Java hashmap method .put()

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

The source code of `java.util.HashMap#put(Object, Object)` is

```
public V put(K key, V value) {

    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

I think that if the keys can get the same index in the table(example:key1 and key2 are all in the table[x]), the `e.hash == hash` will always return true. Is the code `e.hash == hash` neccessary for `.put()` method?

The only one explanation is that the different key.hashCode() after the operate of the `hash()` and `indexFor()` method, the result will be may the same, so the code will be necessary.

Is my answer right? Who can tell me, if `e.hash == hash` is necessary?

Comment: It's not very clear what your problem is. Can you try to elaborate a little bit.

Comment: e.hash != hash can happen?

Answer (score 0):

`e.hash == hash` is just an optimization; it's not strictly necessary.  You're already comparing elements in the same hash bucket, and if two elements are `.equals`, then they match.  The only point is minimizing expensive `.equals` checks on elements whose hashes are the same mod the hash table size.

Comment: e.hash != hash can happen?

Comment: Sure, if the two hashes are the same mod the hash table size.